# Get all versions of an issue in jira

Tags: json, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I need to retrieve all versions (like fix version, confirmer version and affects version) associated with a particular issue in jira. 
I am invoking jira rest api's through java jersey jars. I am able to retrieve status, resolution, etc. through json object but, i am unable to fetch above versions. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert but I think you should be looking for 'fixVersions' in the fields collection.  In Python terms the fixVersions item is a dictionary because there can be multiple Fix Version assignments (at least that happens here).

For me, each element of the dict has several attibutes:
archived: bool
id: int
name: unicode (d-MMM-yy)
releaseDate: unicode (yyyy-mm-dd)
released: bool
self: unicode (url reference)
userReleaseDate: unicode (user formatted date)